# Leaderboard command for leveling system? - discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord, discord.py

So, me and a friend have worked on a level leaderboard command. Here's the code.

```
  @commands.command()
  async def leaderboard(self, ctx):
    with open('level.json', 'r') as fp:
      users = json.load(fp)
      high_score_list = sorted(users, key=lambda x : users[x].get('level', 0), reverse=True)
      message = ''
      for number, user in enumerate(high_score_list):
        message += '{0}. {1} with {2}level\n'.format(number + 1,user, users[user].get('level', 0))
        await ctx.send('{}'.format(high_score_list))
```

But, to our surprise, this showed up.

```
['550912080627236874', '499454400994082826', '578729911284400138', '757122465687273525', '726314322565005382', '472984563447103518', '159985870458322944', '746515506688688178', '733012127576490165', '754945861112430693', '750960499063259196', '359550695042711552', '575252669443211264', '553292456226062367', '744117280312393769']
['578729911284400138', '726314322565005382', '550912080627236874', '359550695042711552', '472984563447103518', '750960499063259196', '159985870458322944', '499454400994082826', '757122465687273525', '553292456226062367', '746515506688688178', '575252669443211264', '733012127576490165', '754945861112430693', '744117280312393769']
['578729911284400138', '726314322565005382', '550912080627236874', '359550695042711552', '472984563447103518', '750960499063259196', '159985870458322944', '499454400994082826', '757122465687273525', '553292456226062367', '746515506688688178', '575252669443211264', '733012127576490165', '754945861112430693', '744117280312393769']
['578729911284400138', '726314322565005382', '550912080627236874', '359550695042711552', '472984563447103518', '750960499063259196', '159985870458322944', '499454400994082826', '757122465687273525', '553292456226062367', '746515506688688178', '575252669443211264', '733012127576490165', '754945861112430693', '744117280312393769']
['578729911284400138', '726314322565005382', '550912080627236874', '359550695042711552', '472984563447103518', '750960499063259196', '159985870458322944', '499454400994082826', '757122465687273525', '553292456226062367', '746515506688688178', '575252669443211264', '733012127576490165', '754945861112430693', '744117280312393769']
['578729911284400138', '726314322565005382', '550912080627236874', '359550695042711552', '472984563447103518', '750960499063259196', '159985870458322944', '499454400994082826', '757122465687273525', '553292456226062367', '746515506688688178', '575252669443211264', '733012127576490165', '754945861112430693', '744117280312393769']
```

It showed up repeatedly, really.
How do we make it so that what shows up is the names on a leaderboard-like form? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you wanna change the last line to `await ctx.send('{}'.format(message))`?

Comment: If the suggestion from AnnieFromTaiwan does not help it might be good to provide a minimal working example (MWE) for the problem you are facing, so others can easily reproduce it.